# Parse.com get PFUser from related PFObject

Tags: iphone, ios, parse-platform

I'm saving a photo to Parse as a PFObject with the `[PFUser currentUser]` user ID as one of its keys.

I want to display the photo in a table view alongside details from that PFUser. But when I try to get the user - `PFUser *user = [self.photo objectForKey:@"user"];` - and then try to access the user's display name, I get the following exception:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', 
reason: 'Key "profilePicture" has no data.  Call fetchIfNeeded before getting 
its value.'
```

Calling fetchIfNeeded crashes the table, though, and the AnyPic tutorial does exactly what I'm trying to do without using fetchIfNeeded. AnyPic just calls `PFUser *user = [self.photo objectForKey:@"user"];` and everything works.

Am I missing a step somewhere? Thanks!

Here's the `cellForRowAtIndexPath`:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath object:(PFObject *)object {
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    PhotoCellTest *cell = (PhotoCellTest *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[PhotoCellTest alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier descriptionText:nil userNameText:nil captionText:nil];
    }

    photo = object;
    PFUser *user = [self.photo objectForKey:@"user"];
    PFFile *profilePictureSmall = [user objectForKey:@"profilePicture"];
    cell.profilePicPlaceholder.file = profilePictureSmall;



    return cell;
}
```

**Edit**

Here's where I set the keys for the PFObject:

```
PFObject *photo = [PFObject objectWithClassName:@"Photo"];
    [photo setObject:[PFUser currentUser] forKey:@"user"];
    [photo setObject:self.photoFile forKey:@"image"];
    [photo setObject:[nameField text] forKey:@"itemCaption"];
```

And here's where I set the keys for the PFUser:

```
PFFile *profilePic = [PFFile fileWithData:data];
    [[PFUser currentUser] setObject:profilePic forKey:@"profilePicture"];
    [[PFUser currentUser] saveInBackground];
```

When I NSLog `user`, I only get `<PFUser:nOpK5splEX:(null)> { }`, but when I NSLog `[PFUser currentUser]`, I get `<PFUser:nOpK5splEX:(null)> { displayName = "XXX";  facebookId = XXX;   profilePicture = "<PFFile: XXX>";  username = XXX;}`... So obviously the PFUser isn't getting set correctly.

Am I supposed to do something in the database to link the user fields or something like that?

Comment: can you post the code where you access the user data?  maybe post the whole cellForRowAtIndexPath method if you do it there.

Comment: Can you show how you are setting the key on the PFObject?

Comment: I agree with @danielbeard.  What leads you to believe there's a value for the key profilePicture?  Also, what kind of object is cell. profilePicPlaceholder?

Comment: See edits above. The NSLog for `user` is blank - it's getting the user ID, but none of its associated fields. When I NSLog currentUser, all the associated fields are populated...

Comment: cell.profilePicPlaceholder is a PFImageView

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Got it figured out - I wasn't using an `includeKey` in the PFQuery.

Comment: i also have the same problem. can you help me?

Answer (score 3):

After

`PFUser *user = [self.photo objectForKey:@"user"];`

you should call

`[user fetchIfNeeded];`